# Match any repetitive pattern using tcl

Tags: regex, tcl, match

I have a binary file that I don't know what is inside. Then, I convert it to hex number using `binary scan $bin_data "H*" hex_data`. The problem is how to match for any repetitive pattern (byte).

### Example 1:

In the file: `0cabab79`
Expected Output: `abab`

### Example 2:

In the file: `0c1f1f03035d`
Expected Output: `1f1f0303`

### Example 3:

In the file: `0c678967895d13`
Expected Output: `67896789`

Comment: Is there a reason for not doing the search over the binary data? `regexp` works just fine on binary data (which is “just a string” with funny characters in it).

Comment: What is the expected output for `0c161656165d13`, `1616` or `61656165`, or `161656165`? In other words, do you expect the first result, the larger result, all the results (even if the two results are overlapping)?

Comment: @DonalFellows the pattern i would like to match is in bytes.  So, i think is it more easier to match in hex.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte the expected output from the example given is 1616

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a more flexible regexp to get all the repeated patterns (at least 2 characters):

```
set inputs [list 0cabab79 0c1f1f03035d 0c678967895d13]
foreach input $inputs {
    set out ""
    foreach {whole sub} [regexp -all -inline {(..+)\1} $input] {
      append out $whole
    }
    puts $out
}
# Output:
# abab
# 1f1f0303
# 67896789
```

---

If you want to make sure the pattern are in pairs of even number of characters (i.e. `aaaaaa` should give `aaaa` and not `aaaaaa`), then...

```
set inputs [list 0cabab79 0c1f1f03035d 0c678967895d13 aaaaaa]
foreach input $inputs {
    set out ""
    foreach {whole sub} [regexp -all -inline {((?:..)+)\1} $input] {
      append out $whole
    }
    puts $out
}
# Output:
# abab
# 1f1f0303
# 67896789
# aaaa
```

Comment: can you pls explain why `[regexp -all -inline {((?:..)+)\1}` can make the pattern are in pairs of even number?  Besides, eg.0c6786785d13 expected result will not match any.  I would like it to be matched in bytes

Comment: @user981714 `(?:..)` will match any 2 characters. `(?:..)+` will match two characters and repeat matching 2 characters. So it will match 2 or 4 or 6 or 8 etc. Then theouter `( ... )` capture the whole thing to be used in `\1`. Does that make sense or should I use another approach to explain this? :)

Comment: I am sorry that i might ask you some questions to further understanding.  1. `{(..+)\1}` vs `{((..)+)\1}`  2.  I would like to match byte.  e.g. 0cababab67867819 result: ababab.  how to do that?

Comment: `(..+)\1` will match at least 2 characters, repeated once. e.g. `abab`, `abcabc` (first part of the pair can be any character long). `((..)+)\1` will match 2 characters, at least once. e.g. `abab`, `abcdabcd` (not `abcabc`), `abcdefabcdef` (first part of the pair can only be of length 2, 4, 6, 8, etc.).

Comment: 2. If you have repeats of more than one, then you can add a `+` to the `\1`, i.e. `((?:..)+)\1+`

Comment: @user981714 That means you have repetitive patterns and not just pairs. You will have to use `((?:..)+)\1+` in my latest comment. Where is `1f1f` in your expected output?

Comment: I am trying with `foreach {whole sub} [regexp -all -inline {(..+)\1+} $input]`.  The result is not correct.  Then, base on the result and pattern, i change `{whole sub}` to `{whole sub1 sub2}`.  Then it is correct.  The question is how many sub is needed?  i don't the reason behind. pls advice

Comment: @user981714 I need you to be very clear when you say something is not working. What is not working, what is the expected output and why this is the expected output. Because you keep using a pattern I have told you won't work for certain cases. E.g. the you use gives [this](http://codepad.org/luI86VFm) but the one I told you to use in my last comment is [this](http://codepad.org/RT6KXQEe).

Comment: And if you're really using `sub1 sub2`, you should be getting weird results. So I really don't see what you're doing.

Comment: i am sorry abt that.  At first i thought `{((?:..)+)\1}` will give the pattern are in pairs of even number of characters (i.e. aaaaaa should give aaaa and not aaaaaa), which is not i want.  So, i chose the {(..+)\1}.  This is the reason why i confuse.

Comment: @user981714 Then what is the string that is failing to give the correct output and why is this output wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regexp using a backreference:

```
regexp -all -inline {(..)\1} 0c1f1f03035d
```

This will return you a list containing the full-length repetition followed by the repeated element for all matches.
So for this one you would get

```
1f1f 1f 0303 03
```

Looping through these you can build your Expected Output e.g.

```
set op {}; 
foreach {rep sing} [regexp -all -inline {(..)\1} 0c1f1f03035d] {
  append op $rep
}
```